# Converting dict object to string in Django/Jinja2 template

Tags: python, django, jinja2

If you use Django or Jinja2, you've probably ran into this problem before.
I have a JSON string that looks like this:

```
{
  "data":{
    "name":"parent",
    "children":[
      {
        "name":"child_a",
        "fav_colors":[
          "blue",
          "red"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"child_b",
        "fav_colors":[
          "yellow",
          "pink"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now I want to pass this to my Jinja2 template:

```
j = json.loads('<the above json here>')
self.render_response('my_template.html', j)
```

...and iterate it like this:

```
<select>
{% for p in data recursive %}
        <option disabled>{{ p.name }}</option>
        {% for c in p.children %}
            <option value="{{ c.fav_colors|safe }}">{{ c.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

This is where I'm having the problem: everything works except Jinja2 outputs unicode encoded values for c.fav_colors. I need c.fav_colors as a valid javascript array so that I can access it from javascript. How can I get Jinja to print that value as ascii text like: `['blue','red']` instead of `[u'blue', u'red']` ?

Comment: No </option> closing tag ? Also, why not [{% for item in c %}"item"{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}] ? This is what templates are for after all: converting python values into whatever needs the view.

Comment: Updated that option tag. The loop syntax I'm using here is for clarity. I'm just trying to showcase the problem: how to output c.fav_colors as valid javascript compatible array: `['blue','red']`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to convert the `fav_colors` list back to JSON. Probably the easiest way to do this would be with a quick template filter:

```
@register.filter
def to_json(value):
    return mark_safe(simplejson.dumps(value))
```

So now you could do

```
<option value="{{ c.fav_colors|to_json }}">
```

Comment: duh! of course. but I'm actually using Jinja2 with webapp2 so now I need to find out how to do '@register.filter' part for Jinja.

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I didn't think of that :-)

Comment: If anybody's wondering how I did this in webapp2: just lookup Jinja2 in webapp2 docs, then do something like this in the BaseHandler class: `j=jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)
j.environment.filters.update({'to_json': to_json})`

Comment: I had to use escape(mark_safe(simplejson.dumps(value))) in order to make it work.
I was using this as part of the data attribute of li element in HTML and dynatree would not parse it correctly if I don't use escape.

Answer (score 0):

Jinja2 now has a `tojson()` filter built-in
https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.tojson

```
{{ my_dict|tojson }}
```

Might not be exactly what OP (or another reader) needs, but worth mentioning here.